# Editar iconos de Google Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

Saben si es posible (refiriendo a derechos), editar los iconos o agregar nuevos en la libreria de Google Material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes modificarlos y redistribuirlos como quieras, ya que la licencia para estos iconos es Opensource. Lo unico que no puedes hacer con ellos es venderlos.

Comment: Hay diferentes tipos de licencias _opensource_, aunque casi todas permiten trabajos derivados no tiene porque ser así siempre, sería distinto si hablamos de licencias de _software libre_. En este caso la licencia es Apache version 2.0: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/LICENSE